# Error '80004005' only when SELECT DISTINCT with ASP Classic

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, ms-access-2007, jet

I am developing in ASP VBScript at work and need to run a SELECT DISTINCT query but I am having some troubles.

I have other queries in my code that work perfectly fine, that do not use SELECT DISTINCT.

Here is what I am using:

```
            Dim sections()
            c = 1
            set conn=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
            set rs=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
            conn.Open "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=******;User ID=Admin;" & _
                    "DATA SOURCE=" & Server.MapPath("modules.mdb")
            rs.open "SELECT DISTINCT section FROM modules WHERE area='First' ORDER BY lvl ASC",conn
            ReDim sections(10)
            do while not rs.EOF
              sections(c) = rs("section")
              c = c + 1
              rs.MoveNext
            loop
            rs.Close
            conn.Close
            set rs = nothing
            set conn = nothing
```

Which gives me this error:

```
error '80004005'
```

on the line of the SQL query

Comment: just thought to check reserved words.. realized 'section' is in there...

Comment: yup that fixed it... woops

Comment: Even if you change the name of the column, I don't see how that SQL statement could work: you're trying to order by a column that is not in the select list.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to  fix this is to use "GROUP BY" instead of "DISTINCT"

```
SELECT DISTINCT section FROM modules WHERE area='First' ORDER BY lvl ASC
SELECT section FROM modules WHERE area='First' GROUP BY section ORDER BY lvl ASC
```